# Web.config not working - Access Control Allow Origin

Tags: iis, xmlhttprequest, cors, cross-domain

I'm making a httprequest from my js code from one domain to another to download some retrieve some images (blob type object). I'm using promise.js to do that. I know the issue related with Access Control Allow Origin header and so I made the required changes to the web.config file and added the following code to it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <configuration> <system.webServer> <httpProtocol> <customHeaders> <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" /> </customHeaders> </httpProtocol> </system.webServer> </configuration>
```

My problem is the Chrome still gives the Access Control Allow Origin issue. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a browser-level protection. You could send an AJAX request to the server asking for the iframe content and the server for that specific request should send a request to the other domain (no cross-browser policies with proxies, yay!) which will respond and then send the content to your page. Just make sure that css, js and other files' relative paths are handled well.